# Does Bootstrap "text-truncate" class work in <label> element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 5.2.2. It appears that the `text-truncate` class does not work in a `<label>` element:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the HTML for that screenshot:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="text-truncate" for="card_printed">Card Printed</label>
      <select name="card_printed" id="card_printed" class="form-select">
        <option value="0" selected>No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="text-truncate" for="certificate_printed">Certificate Printed</label>
      <select name="certificate_printed" id="certificate_printed" class="form-select">
        <option value="0" selected>No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="text-truncate" for="is_duplicate">Is Duplicate</label>
      <select name="is_duplicate" id="is_duplicate" class="form-select">
        <option value="0" selected>No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not aware of any CSS that would override the `text-truncate` class. Looking at the console, I see that `.text-truncate` has the expected styles `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;` and `label` has `display: inline-block;` as needed for truncation.

What am I doing wrong, and what is the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because bootstrap label has property display: inline-block and text-truncate property work only for block.so either override inline-block property or replace label with div.